# Render images into my post content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rendering, blogs, redcarpet

I'm trying to add images to my post which I thought that would be easier but god I've been struggling for a while now.

I tried to use Redcarpet and added some ruby Image_tag code but didn't work. Also I tried with  tag and the raw method but no luck. I don't know I've been going around but I couldn't fine anything and I think I'm not asking nothing weird or complicated ahah.

Just add pictures from my /assets/images folder if is possible.

```
<%= img_tag ("my_photo.jpg")%>
```

How do you recommend to do it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use the image_tag helper and this has always worked fine for me. You could try this:

```
<%= image_tag("my_photo.jpg")%>
```

Comment: Inside your post content?

Comment: in your view file, the .erb file located in app/views/folder

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I used HTML  tag instead of Ruby code.

```
   <%= raw (@post.content) %>
```

As I am using assets pipeline:

```
<img src="/assets/my_photo.jpg" alt="twd" class="img-rounded"></img>
```

My issue was that I was calling my photo as /images/my_photo.jpg instead of /assets/my_photo.jpg... simple as that